# open a doc file in a textarea in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, ms-word

hi anyone help me 
I want to view a doc file in a textarea in jsp technology

here below i find a code but on my system ActiveXObject is not created 
while i enable activex object for ms word in ie but this code not run

can anyone resolve my problem or send me any new code for this purpose?

snook.ca load document

nothing here yet

Answer (score 1):

You can read `.doc` file using `apache-poi` [here](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/java/reading-word-document-in-java) is an example.